# How to do RowFIlter at a textBox using Textchanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

The code I've seen on youtube aren't working. I need to do `Rowfilter` using `TextChanged` event on a `TextBox`.

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;

dv.RowFilter = "Patient_Number LIKE '%" + textBox11.Text + "%'";
```

Then, it will show an error when I start the program:

```
System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column [Patient_Number].'
```

Comment: What's the SELECT query you are using?

Comment: Well, your initial query didn't include that Field or the Field has actually a different name (is it `Patient_Number` - with underscore - or `Patient Number` - with a space?). Or you used an Alias. Or you're trying to filter a different Table.

Comment: impossible to help you because you dont show us the full query. We can only guess like @Jimi did. Help us help you and post the full query

Comment: what is the value of textBox11.Text ? Could it be there is a comma , in there ? Or a qoute ' ?

Comment: Whenever I type any letter. Error message will appear. Can you give me example code to do row filter?